# Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1 RC1 - Deploy to failed targets in a Deployment Group

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We updated our on premise Azure DevOps Server 2019 to Update 1 RC1.  Does somebody know how is this new "Deploy to failed targets in Deployment Group"  feature supposed to work?

- According to [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019u1?view=azure-devops#deploy-to-failed-targets-in-a-deployment-group) it should look like this

[image: Example of Deployment Options from Azure DevOps Server release notes]

- But in our case we don't see "Deploy Options" when clicking "Redeploy"

[image: Screenshot how the same thing looks on our instance]

In this release 1 out of the 10 servers failed, and it would be nice to redeploy only the 1 failed server in the deployment group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked my TFS 2019 update 1 RC 1, no such feature. I submitted this issue to Developer Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/653075/no-deployment-option-feature-in-devops-server-2019.html

Update:

This feature will be will be available from DevOps server 2019 update 1 RC2.